# CKEditor .focus() in instanceReady event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am having problems in setting the focus in instanceReady event of CKEditor 3.4.1. I have already tried the following two ways but both of them are not always working.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(e) { CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.focus(); });


CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',
{
    on :
    {
        instanceReady : function( ev )
        {
            ev.editor.focus();
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Any updates on why the given solutions did not work for you?

Answer (score 22):

or maybe try this, this is much simpler:

use `startupFocus : true`

so your code should look like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',
{
    startupFocus : true,
...
```

Comment: Do you maybe know, how to preserve caret place (where user clicks inside a div[contentEditable].  Your code works (it gives focus, fires instanceCreated event), but caret is always positioned in the beginning of the text inside cke div , regardles, if you clicked on the end of the text in div.

Answer (score 12):

here you go my friend

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',
{
    on :
    {
        instanceReady : function( ev )
        {
            CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.focus();
        }
    }
} );
```

or

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',
{
    on :
    {
        instanceReady : function( ev )
        {
            this.focus();
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: .. It is still the same. Sometimes it is working and sometimes it isn't ... Do you have any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
CKEDITOR.instances['instance-name'].on('instanceReady', function (event) {
            CKEDITOR.instances['instance-name'].focus();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

a bit late but:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'YourEditor', 
{ 
 on:
   {
     instanceReady : function( evt )
     {
       //Set the focus to your editor
       CKEDITOR.instances.YourEditor.focus();
      }
    }
}
```

works fine for me.
Found [here](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Clicking-text-area#forum-topic-top)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to me,

1. find the CKEditor instance, then
2. trigger focus event

   **The critical point is to focus instance in timeout**

   for (var instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
       $timeout(function() {
          CKEDITOR.instances[instance].focus();
       });
    }

Note: I found the instance with a for loop. You may find better way to find the instance

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the above answers worked for me. Here is what I did for **CHROME** and it works just fine:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['instance-name'].container.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirty way (Make sure you read the comment under my answer):

```
jQuery('.cke_wysiwyg_frame').contents().find('body').focus();
```

Comment: Adding focus via jquery will completely bypass the cke focus change and events fired when this is done. You have to use cke focus manager.